# Change Views for tabbed Navigation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

Hi I am new to ruby on rails and I am currently developing a rails app. I have a page with bootstap's tabbed navigation. I want to render different pages on navigating into different tabs.

Currently my page looks like this:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <%= render template: "devise/registrations/edit" %>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="newPage" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new_page-tab">
    <%= render template: "pages/home" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

On this, the home page loads under the `devise/registrations/edit` page. I want them to load only when that particular tab is clicked. Any advices please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to load only when that particular tab is clicked, I think you should use link_to to the direction, here my example

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <%= link_to edit_path do %>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      edit
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to root_path do %>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="newPage" role="tabpanel" aria labelledby="new_page-tab">
      home
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks! But it did not work for me. :(